# Memcached, PHP, why doesn't quit() method work?

Tags: php, memcached, quit

For example I have PHP code

```
<?php   
$memc = new Memcached();
$memc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION, Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT);
$servers = array 
(
    array ("127.0.0.1", 11211),
    array ("127.0.0.1", 11212)
);

$memc->addServers($servers);

if($memc->quit())
        echo "OK!";
?>
```

and when i execute this code I receive: **Fatal error: Call to undefined method Memcached::quit()**

Comment: Perhaps you meant `close()`?

Comment: No, close() also doesn't work, in memcached manual is quit() [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.quit.php)

Comment: What version of PECL's Memcached are you using?

Comment: Yes thank you, I am using version 1.0.2, but quit() is available for 2.0.0 and biggest. But is it important to manually close connection or it will be closed automatically when the script has finished?

Comment: Old question I know, but did you ever work this out? not working for me either, running 2.2.0 (libmemcached 1.0.17)